# Building a dictionary from a file in a class python

Tags: python, class

I am trying to build a class that builds a dictionary from a file that takes the first item in the list and makes it the key and the rest of the items in the list values. So at the end when I call this like

```
neighbors=Neighbors(FileName.txt)
```

but then when I say

```
neighbors['New York']
```

it doesn't return the values for that key

```
class Neighbors(dict):

def __init__(self, fname):
    states=[]
    states1=[]
    states2=[]
    self.fname=open(fname)
    for line in self.fname:
        line=line[:-1]
        states.append(line)
    for line in states:
        states1.append(line.split(','))
    for line in states1:
         item=[x.strip(' ') for x in line]
         states2.append(item)
    a=dict([(t[0],t[1:]) for t in states2])

neighbors = Neighbors("us_states_adjacency.txt")
print neighbors
```

Comment: You need to add the loaded items to `self`, not to `a`

Comment: Also, check the indentation, because the way the code is now, it won't break but I'm pretty sure it won't work the way you want to.

Answer (score 1):

```
def neighbors(fname):
    def make_line(adjacent_cities):
        line = [city.strip() for city in adjacent_cities.split(",")]
        return line[0],line[1:]
    return dict(map(make_line,open(fname)))
```

is how I would do this I think ...

there is no reason to use a class for this ... you just want a dictionary

however if you really wanted it to be a class

```
class Neighbors(dict):
     def __init__(self,fname):
         def make_line(adjacent_cities):
              line = [city.strip() for city in adjacent_cities.split(",")]
              return line[0],line[1:]
         dict.__init__(self,map(make_line,open(fname)))
```

if you dont wnat to impove your original class and you just want to fix it you just need to call the super inits method

```
class Neighbors(dict):

    def __init__(self, fname):
        states=[]
        states1=[]
        states2=[]
        self.fname=open(fname)
        for line in self.fname:
            line=line[:-1]
            states.append(line)
        for line in states:
            states1.append(line.split(','))
        for line in states1:
             item=[x.strip(' ') for x in line]
             states2.append(item)
        dict.__init__(self,[(t[0],t[1:]) for t in states2]) # call super constructor on our dict ...
```

here is a simpler class that overrides dict ...

```
class dummy(dict):
  def __init__(self,initializer):
      dict.__init__(self,initializer)

d = dummy([('a',2),('b',4)])
print d['a']
print d['c']
```

Comment: i have to use a class to solve this.. This is what I have to do exactly..                                                         Notice that this is a subclass of dict. Therefore, this class is essentially a dictionary. The key is anindividual state name, and the value is the list of neighbors of that state. This dictionary is 
populated the constructor of the Neighbors class, which reads the text lines from the us_states_adjacency.txt file splits them by comma, strips the surrounding spaces, and in the end stores the data in the dictionary

Comment: thanks when i run this neighbors= Neighbors("us_states_adjacency.txt") and  then say print neighbors it prints the dictionary with the keys as the states and there values. But for example when I say neighbors['New York'] I am getting error that says Neighbors instance has no attribute getitem??? Do I need to define another function __getitem__???

Comment: I added a simpler example ... since I dont have your text file I cant really test against it